# SimpleCursorAdapter issue - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor"

Tags: java, android, cursor, autocompletetextview, simplecursoradapter

I've read similar topics and didn't find any answer that I could apply to my situation.

Long story short, I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` with `SimpleCursorAdapter`. It queries my `SQLiteDatabase` for the matching drop down list of options.

Everything works fine, but **when I press the "Home" button** (`onPause() -> onStop()`) if I've shortly before that used the `AutoCompleteTextView`, upon re-entering the app (`onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume()`), I get this error:

> 03-05 19:17:42.186 13847-13847/com.ardovic.weatherappprototype
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.ardovic.weatherappprototype, PID: 13847
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.ardovic.weatherappprototype/com.ardovic.weatherappprototype.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed
>   cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2cae0855
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4084)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1749)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an
>   already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2cae0855
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6660)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6688)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4042)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4084) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1749) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

**It doesn't point to any of my code lines**, so I suppose that it's the SimpleCursorAdapter problem. Here is the code for it (I've commented out unrelated parts, but they are still there):

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.dropdown_text,
                        null,
                        new String[]{CITY_COUNTRY_NAME},
                        new int[]{R.id.text});
        actvCityCountryName.setAdapter(adapter);
        actvCityCountryName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

//                cityCountryName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CITY_COUNTRY_NAME));
//                actvCityCountryName.setText(cityCountryName);
//                JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
//                task.execute(new String[]{cityCountryName});

            }
        });
        adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
                final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CITY_COUNTRY_NAME);
                final String cityCountryName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                return (cityCountryName);
            }
        });
        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
//                cursor = getMatchingStates((constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
                return cursor;
            }
        });
```

I've **already tried** various suggestions, like calling `stopManagingCursor(cursor)`, `cursor.requery()`, `actvCityCountryName.dismissDropDown()`, `actvCityCountryName.clearListSelection()`, or `actvCityCountryName.clearFocus()` in various places and lifecycle methods.

Looking forward for any suggestions that would solve this problem, thanx in advance!

Comment: It may be that you have closed the database, this will effectively close the cursor.

Comment: @MikeT - I've tried doing that but unsuccessful. I've been recommended to try this, maybe you could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254716/migrating-to-cursorloader-loadermanager-for-autocompletetextview-with-sqliteda